# jquery toggle class on toggled sidenav

Tags: jquery, toggle, toggleclass

Basically if you look at my example, you will see you click on a link, which initiates the toggle, and you can then click another link and it'll toggle the next panel in.

My problem is, on the real thing, im planning to use a sprite for an icon, and in order to minus the background position to the right position i need an 'active' class applied to the link with the toggle activated. I believe i'm looking at it all wrong in my example as i'm just applying a class to the clicked link. I'm not sure how to apply it in the way i wish, or if indeed it's possible.

My code is:

http://jsfiddle.net/visualdecree/4A23Z/5/

Comment: I don't quite understand what it is you are trying to achieve. What are you trying to achieve, what is preventing you from doing it? And what are the steps needed to reproduce this issue?

Comment: updated question to try explain it better, sorry about that

Comment: Are any of the answers close to addressing what you're looking for? You have a hyphen (-) in your question, there are words missing there, what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I am understanding the problem...

http://jsfiddle.net/4A23Z/8/

I put in styling to highlight the active menu item.  Added code to remove all active classes on the LI's before toggling the active LI.

```
ul.sidenav li.active { background:cyan; }

 $('.sn').click(function(){
    $('ul.sidenav li').removeClass('active');                 
    $(this).stop(true,true).toggleClass("active");
});​
```

**EDIT:**

http://jsfiddle.net/4A23Z/10/

```
$('.sn').click(function(){
    $('ul.sidenav li').removeClass('active');                    
    $(this).stop(true,true).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: This appears to work for me, i was missing the remove class part. Thanks for this

Comment: I noticed one thing, if you click the same link to close the menu, the active is not removed, is there anything i can add to remedy this?

Comment: If you check out http://jsfiddle.net/visualdecree/4A23Z/11/ i have it so you can click to open the menu, click again to close, but it's not removing the class upon hiding the menu when you click the same link.

Answer (score 0):

If I undertand you correctly - try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4A23Z/7/) (or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4A23Z/9/) with active class defined)

```
$(".sn a").on('click',function(){
    var panID = $("#" + $(this).data('panel') );
    $("div[id*='sn-pan-']").hide({slide:'toggle'}, 1000);
    var link = this;
    $(panID).css("left","100px").animate({width:'toggle'}, 500, function()                      { 
        $(".sn a").removeClass("active");
        $(link).toggleClass("active");
    })
})

 ​
```

Comment: it does not seem to be much different

Comment: Behavior - yes. But >Basically trying to get a class on the active item on the navigation bar. Active class is on active link in sidebar after click